# How to print IPv4 and IPv6 separately on web page

Tags: python, ipv6, ipv4

This file is in my website and every time I or clients run, we get the public IP Address. Since I have enabled IPv6 in my server, if client has public IPv6 it will show him, else he'll see his IPv4.

```
#!/home/path/virtualenv/folder/3.7/bin//python
print ("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
print('<title>IP | DOMAIN</title>')

import os
ip = os.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]

ip2 = ('Your IP is: <span style=\'color:red;font-weight:bold;\'>{}</span>'.format(ip))
print(ip2)
```

As I figured out, `REMOTE_ADDR` displays whether IPv6 or IPv4 to the client, based on which one he has.

What I want is to show these two IPs separately, like this:

If he has IPv4, display `your ipv4 is: {ipv4}`.

If he has IPv6, display `your ipv6 is: {ipv6}`.

Since all the clients at least have one of them, there should be two `if` conditions.

I want something like https://whatismyipaddress.com/ that shows both IPv4 and IPv6.

Comment: You can include something like two one pixel images that are retrieved only via one of  each of the IPs. That way, you can get an address of each IP that the client uses.

Comment: I'm afraid I did not understand what to do

Answer (score 0):

```
from ipaddress import ip_address, IPv4Address
  
def validIPAddress(IP: str) -> str:
    try:
        return "IPv4" if type(ip_address(IP)) is IPv4Address else "IPv6"
    except ValueError:
        return "Invalid"
  
if __name__ == '__main__' :  
        
    # Enter the Ip address 
    Ip = "192.168.0.1"
    print(validIPAddress(Ip)) 
  
    Ip = "2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334"
    print(validIPAddress(Ip)) 
  
    Ip = "256.32.555.5"
    print(validIPAddress(Ip))  
  
    Ip = "250.32:555.5"
    print(validIPAddress(Ip))
```

The output for the given example is:

```
IPv4
IPv6
Invalid
Invalid
```

This way you can use the method in order to create the string you want to display AND use the method for other things also :)

Comment: But if I run this script in a web page, it does not show me my IP